# not able to see application sandbox on Mac OSX Lion (10.7.2)

Tags: xcode4.2, osx-lion

I have just downloaded XCode 4.2 for Lion from apple developer tools available on developer portal. But I am not able to see the sandbox for the project on my iMac. It must be under the path /Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator, but i am not seeing any folder named iPhone Simulator inside the Application Support.
The Mac Version is 10.7.2 and the simulator I am running on is 5.0.

EDIT: I have got it...
WTF..... They have made the app sandboxing too much secure on mac os Lion... You will have perform do 2-3 additional processes to enable it... [EnablingSandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html) [NewInOSXLion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_7.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac OSX Lion, Apple have hidden /Library to ensure novice users can't delete application data or change it by mistake. If you want to show it, open terminal and type or copy/paste the following:

chflags nohidden ~/Library/

This will show your library folder again.

Comment: You can use Finder > Go > (Hold Option key) > Library